# Disable Check-in on Main without applying to Dev Branch

Tags: tfs

In my TFS project structure I have a Development, Main and Release structure where I branch from Main into Development and then Merge back.  I want to remove checkout/checkin access to Main and only allow the development team access to merge code back from Development.

However, if I do this, the branch created in Development inherits the permissions from Main that disallows checkins/checkouts.  How do I force the new Development branch to inherit permissions from the Development parent, not the source of the branch?

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on your development branch and select "Security" you can change to not "Inherit" permissions and configure it how you like independently.

Comment: I actually want it to inherit permissions from the dev branch.  The problem is that it seems by default when I branch into the dev branch it is bringing over the permissions from the Main branch and not inheriting from dev at all.

Comment: Do you mean Development folder? Where you keep your development branches that inherit their permission from whence they were branched? That is by design and the expected and wanted behavior for most folks. You can set the permission differently per branch as needed.